# Javascript Reduce on Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object

```
0:
{
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  score: 50,
}

1:
{
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  score: 22,
};
.
.
.
more...
```

I want to sum their scores using reduce.
I know it can be done with for loop to turn that into scoreArray and reduce. Is there any efficient way to use reduce on object data so I don't need to do use for loop or create unnecessary array?

Comment: You already have an array. Otherwise there wouldn't be a `.reduce()` to use in the first place.

Comment: The kind of "Object" you're talking about suggest you're talking about an **array of objects** instead, if so, you can just use `reduce` over it.

Comment: Try `arr.reduce((a, v) => a + v.score, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `reduce` on the array of objects:

```js
let arr = [
  { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", score: 50 },
  { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", score: 22, }
];

let sum = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + obj.score, 0);
console.log(sum);
```